# SQL Duplicates remove

Tags: t-sql, null, duplicates, rows

I've a problem of duplicates in tsql. How can I remove? 
This is my output:

```
  id          name       ref
----------- ---------- --------------
1           John       null
1           John       RE
2           Smith      null
2           Smith      DOS
3           Van        null
4           Sam        CR
5           Bob        null
```

Code:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
    u.id,
    u.name,
    c.ref
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN con c on c.id=u.id
```

I would like the output to be like this:

```
  id          name       ref
----------- ---------- --------------
1           John       RE
2           Smith      DOS
3           Van        null
4           Sam        CR
5           Bob        null
```

This is just an example, I've few of them.

thanks

Comment: what is the table definition of your tables users and con?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using MAX and GROUP BY:

```
 SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.name,
    MAX(c.ref) as Ref
 FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN con c on c.id=u.id
 GROUP BY 
    u.id,
    u.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query, this will give you the exact required output:

```
DECLARE @SAMPLEDATA TABLE(id INT,        name VARCHAR(100),      ref VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @SAMPLEDATA VALUES
(1,           'John',       null),
(1,           'John',       'RE'),
(2,           'Smith',      null),
(2,           'Smith',      'DOS'),
(3,          'Van',        null),
(4,           'Sam',        'CR'),
(5,           'Bob',        null)
 ;WITH SAMPLEDATA
 AS
 (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100))SNO,* FROM @SAMPLEDATA
 )
 SELECT ID,NAME,REF FROM(
 SELECT * ,ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN T2.ID=T1.id AND T1.ref IS NULL THEN 'R'     ELSE 'NR' END
 FROM SAMPLEDATA T2 WHERE T2.SNO=T1.SNO+1),'NR')COL FROM SAMPLEDATA T1) DATA     WHERE COL='NR'
```

OUTPUT

```
------------------
ID  NAME    REF
------------------
1   John    RE
2   Smith   DOS
3   Van     NULL
4   Sam     CR
5   Bob     NULL
------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of below query:

```
    DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
    (id INT, name VARCHAR(10),ref VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
    (1,'John',null),
    (1,'John','RE'),
    (2,'Smith',null),
    (2,'Smith','DOS'),
    (3,'Van',null),
    (4,'Sam','CR'),
    (5,'Bob',null)

    SELECT id,name,ref FROM
    (
     SELECT 
        id,name,ref,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,name ORDER BY ref DESC)
     FROM 
        @TABLE
    ) AS A
    WHERE RN < 2
```

You can use this too:

```
     SELECT 
        u.id,
        u.name,
        MAX(u.ref) as Ref
     FROM 
        @TABLE u
     GROUP BY 
        u.id,
        u.name
```